# Is FTP on router secure?

Tags: networking, router, security, encryption, ftp

I am using a 2TB external hard drive connected to an Asus RT-AC87U.
The router can be accessed from the internet over `FTP` with the right username and password.

My question is, that how secure is this connection?

I know that it is protected with the user/pass, but I am thinking of encryption. Is it possible for someone to intercept the connection and get the transferred data?

Also, how would it be possible to make it more secure? I know that there is a protocol called `SFTP` for encrypted file transfer. Is possible somehow to use `SFTP` instead of `FTP`, or what other possibilities do I have to increase security?

In the routers menu I did not find anything related to security with the `FTP` server.

You can have a look at the routers menu here: http://event.asus.com/2012/nw/dummy_ui/en/

EDIT:

The solutions I have got so far are way better than I expected, but to be clear about my whole concept here is that I can not really afford a server for 24/24 uptime. However I am looking for an easy solution for my users to be able to access parts of the share and be able to download/upload data in a more secure way. They are not that experienced; I even had to write a step by step guide for them to be able to map the share as a network location.
I would like to keep things easy for them but also as secure as possible.

Comment: As we've said, if your router does not support SFTP then this is not an option for you. If your router has VPN capability then you can configure this and find instructions to give to your users to setup their computers. Your limited hardware and requirements don't give you many options...

Comment: upgrade to Asuswrt-Merlin and you will have SFTP support on your AC-87U Router

Comment: @Devid thank you, I will try it and give a feedback

Answer (score 5):

Unencrypted FTP is just that. An attack that intercepts your data (very unlikely in “normal” countries, by the way) can read both login credentials and data transfers.

SFTP is not related to FTP at all. Instead, it uses a SSH connection. As such, it’s very secure, as long as you have reasonable credentials. Like SSH, it supports public key authentication.

There’s also FTP-ES (FTP with explicit SSL/TLS), it also runs on port 21. In this mode, a plaintext session starts where the client, after querying server capabilities, tells the server to start an encrypted session. Usually, both command and data sessions are encrypted, though the client can control that. Because it starts with a regular plaintext session, it’s backwards compatible.

Then, there’s FTP implicit SSL/TLS. It works like HTTPS, so there’s no unencrypted part. However, it’s not backwards compatible and as such must run on a different port, usually 990. It’s pretty much a legacy method of encrypting FTP.

It’s very unlikely your router supports encrypted FTP. If it supports SFTP, that’s a relatively painless option. There are many clients like WinSCP.

Comment: So, does my router supports any of these? Do I have a solution for this problem? Where should I start?

Comment: @Divin3 No, it doesn’t. You might have better luck with the third-party Merlin firmware. It does support the “optware” way of installing any software on the router. That’s a pretty advanced feature though, so unless you have Linux experience, I recommend not doing it.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I think altering the firmware may cause the product to lose the warranty. Also I am not experienced in Linux, but I am a fast learner. I updated the post with more information.

Answer (score 4):

Non-encrypted FTP has the username and password sent by plaintext and is not secure.

SFTP is far better but if your router does not have this capability then you're out of luck.

Does your router have any VPN capability which might then offer you better security when FTP'ing to your drive? If not then, again, you're out of luck.

If you want encrypted transfer then create an SFTP server or create a VPN to your LAN.

Comment: Yes, id does support VPN, do I have any other solution for a direct connection?

Comment: Not unless you buy/create your own server(s) that have the functionality you desire... a VPN should be the easiest solution for you. Just make sure your router allows you to connect to the hard disk via the VPN...

Comment: You are right, the router does support VPN and it sounds as a good solution. I have updated the post with some more information.